# How to set the whole installer invisible while using 'ExecWait' in NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I'm  installing a program with my installer and run it with 'ExecWait'.

Is there a way to hide the window of the installer while the program is executed?

The installer should show up again and continue when the user quits the executed program.

Is there any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HideWindow
ExecWait '"$InstDir\Foo.exe" "space bar" /baz'
BringToFront
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitor, when you add some explanations for your intension.

Comment: @reporter: All of the commands are documented in the NSIS documentation. Other than the fact that BringToFront will make the window visible and try to bring it to the front in one operation I don't see how anything is unclear in this little sample...

Comment: These additional facts would have been made your answer perfect :-)